# Getting "invalidCategoryId" error message in YouTube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There seems to be an error when uploading a video to YouTube using the API when using the "Videoblogging" category which has an ID of 21. I even used the document to retrieve the ID at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list under the "Try it" section.

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPLdRMlQU3wwNcowdAUs/EapFaGYG7K0StIXVf8aba249tdM\"",
   "id": "21",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Videoblogging",
    "assignable": false
}
```

With other categories such as Sports

```
{
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPLdRMlQU3wwNcowdAUs/9GQMSRjrZdHeb1OEM1XVQ9zbGec\"",
   "id": "17",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Sports",
    "assignable": true
}
```

The only difference is Assignable, so are categories which aren't assignable won't work as the documentation around this area isn't clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [VideoCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories#properties)

> **snippet.assignable**
>
> - Indicates whether videos can be associated with the category.

Based on this document, it seems that assignable with a false value will return a “invalidCategoryId” error message for associating a video with this category.

Hope this helps

Comment: What, then, is the purpose of unassignable categories?